About BMO space on smooth bounded domains
Let $\Omega$ be any  domain(open and connected) in $\Bbb R^d$.
Define the $\text{BMO}(\Omega)$ space as
$$ \text{BMO}(\Omega)= \big\{u\in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)\,\,:\,\, |u|_{\text{BMO}(\Omega)} <\infty \big\},
$$
with the seminorm,
$$|u|_{\text{BMO}(\Omega)}
=\sup_{B_r(x_0) \subset \Omega} \frac{1}{|B_r(x_0)|} \int_{B_r(x_0)} \Big| u(x) - \frac{1}{|B_r(x_0)|} \int_{B_r(x_0)} u(z) \,d z \Big| d x.$$
Let us consider the seminorm
$$|u|^*_{\text{BMO}(\Omega)}
=\sup_{x_0\in \Omega,\, r>0} \frac{1}{|\Omega\cap B_r(x_0)|} \int_{\Omega\cap B_r(x_0)} \Big| u(x) - \frac{1}{|\Omega\cap B_r(x_0)|} \int_{ \Omega\cap B_r(x_0)} u(z) \,d z \Big| d x.
$$
In particular,
$$ |u|^*_{\text{BMO}(\Bbb R^d)}=|u|_{\text{BMO}(\Bbb R^d)}.$$
Question:
1- Are the seminorms $|\cdot|_{\text{BMO}(\Omega)}$ and $|\cdot|^*_{\text{BMO}(\Omega)}$ when  $\Omega$ is a $d$-set? That is there is $C>0$ such that
$$ |u|^*_{\text{BMO}(\Omega)}\leq C|u|_{\text{BMO}(\Omega)}$$
for $u\in \text{BMO}(\Omega)$
Note that we clearly have $$  |u|_{\text{BMO}(\Omega)}\leq |u|^*_{\text{BMO}(\Omega)}$$
Recall that  $\Omega$ is a $d$-set if there is $c>0$ such that $|\Omega\cap B_r(a)|\geq cr^d$ for all $a\in \Omega$ and $r>0$. For instance an example of a d-set, is a Lipschitz domain.  $\Omega=\Bbb R^d_+=\{x\in \Bbb R^d\,\,:\,\, x_d>0\}$ is also a $d$-set.
2- Is the John Nuremberg inequality true on $(\text{BMO}(\Omega),|\cdot|_{\text{BMO}(\Omega)})$? That is there are $a>0, b>0$ such that
any ball  $B\subset \Omega$ and $u\in \text{BMO}(\Omega)$ there holds that
\begin{align*}
|\{x \in B : |u(x) - u_B| > t\}| &\leq a |B|
\exp\Big(\frac{-b t}{|u|_{\text{BMO}(\Omega)}}\Big).
\end{align*}
for any ball $B\subset \Omega$ and $t>0$
Any reference or answer is welcome.

A characterisation of domains satisfying a relevant inequality can be found in the paper:
Staples, Susan G., $L^p$-averaging domains and the Poincaré inequality, Ann. Acad. Sci. Fenn., Ser. A I, Math. 14, No. 1, 103-127 (1989). ZBL0706.26010.
The condition is defined through the quasi-hyperbolic metric
$$ k(x,y) = \inf_{\gamma} \int_{\gamma} \frac1{\mathrm{dist}(z,\partial \Omega)} \,\mathrm{d}z,$$
where the infimum is taken over all rectifiable curves $\gamma$ connecting $x$ and $y$. The paper proves that, a domain $\Omega$ is $L^p$-averaging in that
$$ \frac1{|\Omega|} \int_{\Omega} \lvert u - (u)_{\Omega}\rvert \,\mathrm{d}x \lesssim \sup_{B \subset \Omega} \frac1{|B|} \int_{B} \lvert u - (u)_{\Omega}\rvert \,\mathrm{d}x \quad\mbox{for all } u \in \mathrm{BMO}(\Omega)$$
if and only if
$$ \int_{\Omega} k(x,x_0) \,\mathrm{d} x < \infty$$
for some (and hence every) $x_0 \in \Omega$. Moreover if this holds, we also have the equivalence of norms. You can find these results in Theorem 2.1 (necessity) and Theorem 2.6 (sufficiency) in the above paper.
The John-Nirenberg inequality then follows if you additionally impose an exponential integrability condition on $k(\cdot,x_0)$. Domains where the latter holds are known as Hölder domains, and are discussed in detail in:
Smith, Wayne; Stegenga, David A., Exponential integrability of the quasi-hyperbolic metric on Hölder domains, Ann. Acad. Sci. Fenn., Ser. A I, Math. 16, No. 2, 345-360 (1991). ZBL0725.46024.
Finally I'll mention that by Lemma 3.11 of
Gehring, F. W.; Martio, O., Lipschitz classes and quasiconformal mappings, Ann. Acad. Sci. Fenn., Ser. A I, Math. 10, 203-219 (1985). ZBL0584.30018.
we see that John domains are Hölder domains, which gives a large class of domains where these results holds true. I don't believe there is a direct connection between such domains and $d$-sets however; think of domains with lots of "cracks" that are not detected by the measure, which would be a $d$-set where $k(\cdot,x_0)$ is not integrable.

Edit: Upon reflection, I don't think the cited sources give an affirmative answer to the validity of $\lVert \cdot \rVert^{\ast}_{\mathrm{BMO}(\Omega)} \lesssim \lVert \cdot \rVert_{\mathrm{BMO}(\Omega)}$.
As a partial answer, I will mention the following paper of Jones:
Jones, Peter W., Extension theorems for BMO, Indiana Univ. Math. J. 29, 41-66 (1980). ZBL0432.42017.
which proves that if $\Omega$ is a uniform domain, then $\mathrm{BMO}$ defined using $\lVert \cdot \rVert^{\ast}_{\mathrm{BMO}(\Omega)}$ admits an extension operator $\mathrm{BMO}(\Omega) \to \mathrm{BMO}(\mathbb R^n)$. Thus, if $\Omega$ is both a uniform domain and a $d$-set, then $\lVert \cdot \rVert^{\ast}_{\mathrm{BMO}(\Omega)} \lesssim \lVert \cdot \rVert_{\mathrm{BMO}(\Omega)}$ follows by taking an extension and restricting to balls in $\Omega$, where we have $\lvert \Omega \cap B \rvert \simeq \lvert B \rvert$.
Note that uniform domains are more general than John domains (and hence the other conditions given in this answer), but they do include Lipschitz domains.

Thank you very much for this thorough and expertise answer. Especially all mentioned article are worth going through them.

I don’t know if the following can be useful, maybe it’s stuff that you know already.
The definition of BMO can be given in large generality for metric measure spaces $(X,d,\mu)$ of homogeneous type (that is, a metric spaces $(X,d)$ with a doubling measure $\mu$). The John-Nirenberg inequality always holds for BMO in that setting (the paper of reference I know is by Coifman and Weiss, 1977 “Extensions of Hardy spaces and their use in analysis”).
It should be easy to prove that if $\Omega$ is a d-set, it is a doubling metric measure spaces (with distance and measure inherited from the ones on the Euclidean space), so all the standard theory applies to the norm $|\cdot|_{\mathrm {BMO}}^*(\Omega)$, including the inequality of John-Nirenberg.
About the first norm you defined, the only thing I see at the moment is that the two can be equivalent only if $\Omega$ is connected, otherwise I don’t have intuition on what is going on with that norm. Actually I would be curious to see an answer.

Thanks for this answer. I overlooked the fact that $d$-set also  enjoys doubling condition. Note that by domain I meant open and connected. So here $\Omega$ is connected. I be happy how you elaborate in this case.

Ok. You wrote “any open set” before, that’s why I wrote that. I don’t know what is the relation between the two norms, not even with smooth boundaries. Maybe it’s not hard, but I have no clue. First thing I would do is try to find a counterexample, something that oscillates on the boundary of the set so that the oscillation over small balls that touch the boundary is finite, but over large balls that intersect the boundary, the oscillation is infinite
